# Dropdown Menu Fusion Table Filtering

Tags: google-maps, filtering, google-fusion-tables

I've got a question related to the filtering of different columns in Fusion Tables.

**Goal:** I would like to create a map that shows the location of American football teams and the location of American football fan clubs in Belgium.

**What I've done so far with your help:**

I've started to create a map using two different overlays (coming from two different Fusion Tables: one 'Clubs' table with the American football teams and one 'Fans' table with the American football fan clubs).

I've also implemented two checkboxes that can turn each layer on and off.

I've finally also managed to create a filtering search box that helps me filter the 'Number' column from the 'Fans' table. So I can refresh that layer and only show the fan clubs with more than x fans (the 'Clubs' layer remains unchanged).

**Where I am stuck:**

I have actually three columns that I would like to be able to filter with a search box:

- 'Number' (total number of fans)
- 'Number Male' (total number of male fans)
- 'Number Female' (total number of female fans)

Is there any way to create two dropdown menus: one selecting the column I want to filter and one selecting the filtering option ('greater than', 'equal to' or 'lower than')?

I've added the code I have so far in attachment. I would be so grateful if someone could help me out with this:

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<h3>American Football in Belgium</h3>
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
  #map_canvas { height: 100% }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDjB2uAt9B6cFcUiJAgANg63qNQtiF6v24&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleLayer(this_layer){
  if(this_layer.getMap()) {
    this_layer.setMap(null)
  } else {
    this_layer.setMap(map);
  }
}
var layer1=null;
var layer2=null;
var map=null;

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.809406, 4.498901),
    zoom: 9,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  layer1 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: 'Fans Location',
      from:'1_n9DXwEAdVtmHhvypRxpjgk7DMJVbmBbYgsUfdQ'
    },
    map: map
  });
  layer2 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: 'Club Location',
      from:'1waRLQMKE1bJKNT4qBesLQUNcjbezPeln6z1XQKA'
    },
    map: map
  });
}
function refreshLayer() {
  var numFans = parseInt(document.getElementById('numberFans').value);
  if (!isNaN(numFans)) {
    layer1.setOptions({
      query: {
        select: 'Fans Location',
        from:'1_n9DXwEAdVtmHhvypRxpjgk7DMJVbmBbYgsUfdQ',
        where: "'Number' > "+numFans
      }
    });
  } else {
    layer1.setOptions({
      query: {
        select: 'Fans Location',
        from:'1_n9DXwEAdVtmHhvypRxpjgk7DMJVbmBbYgsUfdQ'
      }
    });
  }
}
</script></head>
<body onload="initialize();">
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="show_hide_layer1" checked onchange="toggleLayer(layer1)"/>
  <label> Fans </label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="show_hide_layer2" checked onchange="toggleLayer(layer2)"/>
  <label> Clubs </label>
<div>
  <label> Number Fans greater than:</label><input type="text" id="numberFans" ></input>
  <input type="button" id="query" value="Refresh Layer" onclick="refreshLayer();">
</input>
</div>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:80%; height:80%"></div>
<script src="http://www.google-analytics.com/urchin.js" type="text/javascript"> 
</script> 
</body>
```